# Python: Plot a figure saved in a tuple outside the console (not inline)

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to know how it is possible to get my figure plotted out of the console (not inline but interactive) which is saved in a tuple. A function I wrote saves it in there. The code is not very sophisticated but it's a basic problem. Here it is:

## Script1.py:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def R():
    x = np.arange(-5,6,0.01)
    global y1, y2
    y1 = np.sin(x)
    y2 = np.cos(x)
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(y1), plt.plot(y2)
    return y1, y2, fig1
```

## Script2.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Script1 import *

y = R()
```

This saves, like I wish, the data of R() in y (tuple with size 3 with the figure at index 2) in the 2nd script. The figure gets plotted and everything works fine. But when I want to access that figure at a later moment again, like typing y[2], it will always be plotted in the IPython console, not interactively out of it. Is there an elegant way doing this?